# How to an image respecting the image editor crop in controller? TYPO3

Tags: typo3, typo3-8.x

how can I get an image path from a record in the controller respecting the crop settings from the back end image editor?

My current code (in the model) only gives me the the image with no crop but with the adjusted dimensions.

```
public function getImageUrl($imageResource)
    {
        return $imageResource->getOriginalResource()->getOriginalFile()->getPublicUrl();
    }

    public function getSmallImage($imageResource)
    {
        $image = $this->imageService->getImage($this->getImageUrl($imageResource), null, false);

        $processingInstructions = [
            'maxWidth' => 500,
            'maxHeight' => 500
        ];
        $processedImage = $this->imageService->applyProcessingInstructions($image, $processingInstructions);
        return $this->imageService->getImageUri($processedImage);
    } 

public function getSmallImage($imageResource)
    {
        $image = $this->imageService->getImage($this->getImageUrl($imageResource), null, false);

        $processingInstructions = [
            'maxWidth' => 500,
            'maxHeight' => 500
        ];
        $processedImage = $this->imageService->applyProcessingInstructions($image, $processingInstructions);
        return $this->imageService->getImageUri($processedImage);
    }
```

Must I feed the crop to the `$processingInstructions`? Where to find the crop?

I am using TYPO3 8.7.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution in the image view helper class of fluid.

```
public function getSmallImage($imageResource)
    {
    $image = $this->imageService->getImage($this->getImageUrl($imageResource), null, false);
    $cropVariantCollection = \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Imaging\ImageManipulation\CropVariantCollection::create((string)$imageResource->getOriginalResource()->getProperty('crop'));
    $cropArea = $cropVariantCollection->getCropArea('default');
    $processingInstructions = [
        'maxWidth' => 500,
        'maxHeight' => 500,
        'crop' => $cropArea->makeAbsoluteBasedOnFile($image),
    ];

    $processedImage = $this->imageService->applyProcessingInstructions($image, $processingInstructions);
    return $this->imageService->getImageUri($processedImage);
    }
```